# How can I call a function using an if statement and then print the value returned inside the if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

This part of my if statement calls the `find_feed` function and it it returns `None`, the if statement completes, however if it returns anything else, the else statement re-calls the function: `news_feed = feedparser.parse(find_feed(user_input))`

Instead of calling the function twice (because it takes a bit to complete), I'd like to call it once and if it doesn't return None, use the returned value in the else statement instead of calling the function again. Can I do that, and if so, how?

```py
    elif find_feed(user_input) is None:
        print("No location found.")
    else:
        print("Pulling weather data from Environment Canada.")
        news_feed = feedparser.parse(find_feed(user_input))
        brief_current()
        more_question = input("\n" + "Would you like more details? (y or n) ")
        if more_question == "y":
            detailed_current()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) in Python 3.8 you can also combine `if` statement with assignment so you don't have to create the variable in advance:

```py
    elif (unparsed_news_feed := find_feed(user_input)) is None:
        print("No location found.")
    else:
        print("Pulling weather data from Environment Canada.")
        news_feed = feedparser.parse(unparsed_news_feed)
        brief_current()
        more_question = input("\n" + "Would you like more details? (y or n) ")
        if more_question == "y":
            detailed_current()
```

Although here I'd suggest swapping two branches and inverting `is None` to `is not None` so `unparsed_news_feed` is only used in its corresponding branch.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about `:=`. The branches part of your answer, you're saying that the `else` statement should be `print("No location found.")` and the `elif` should contain the current `else` code, but with `is Not None` instead. Am I understanding right? Sorry if this is confusing, I'm new to SO and Python.

Comment: @aidenmitchell Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Store the return value in a variable, so you can reference it later. See here:

```
xy = find_feed(x)

# Assumes a pre existing if statement

elif xy is None:
    print('no location')
else:
    print("Pulling weather data from Environment Canada.")
    news_feed = feedparser.parse(xy)
    brief_current()
    more_question = input("\n" + "Would you like more details? (y or n) ")
    if more_question == "y":
        detailed_current()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the result of the call to `find_feed` before you test its value:

```
else: # instead of the original elif find_feed(user_input) is None:
    result = find_feed(user_input)
    if result is None:
        print("No location found.")
    else:
        print("Pulling weather data from Environment Canada.")
        news_feed = feedparser.parse(result)
        brief_current()
        more_question = input("\n" + "Would you like more details? (y or n) ")
        if more_question == "y":
            detailed_current()
```